# How to animate the width and height of a Layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-animation

I have a `LinearLayout` which is expanded to full screen by hiding all other layouts and views on `onClick`. There is a `Relativelayout` above `LinearLayout`

I want to apply custom animation on this. The size should should increase slowly (like in 500 milli seconds).

But I doubt is it possible? Thanks.

Here is what I am doing `onClick`:

```
private void expandView (int viewId) {
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) ((LinearLayout) view.findViewById(viewId)).getParent();
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams rlMargin = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();
    rlMargin.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(rlMargin);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) relativeLayout.getParent();
    hideAllLinearLayoutExcept(linearLayout.getId());
    hideAllTilesExcept(viewId);
}
```

`viewId` is the id of the `LinearLayout` I am clicking. This function is called from `onClick()`

Comment: So you want to animate the width and height of the RelativeLayout?

Comment: Yes It is automatically increasing in size

Comment: Allright, see my answer below.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Sure that is possible.**

Simply write your own custom-animation and modify the `LayoutParams` of your animated view.
In this example, the animation animates the **height** of the animated View. Of course, **animating the width is also possible**.

This is how it could look like:

```
public class ResizeAnimation extends Animation {

    private int startHeight;
    private int deltaHeight; // distance between start and end height
    private View view;

    /**
     * constructor, do not forget to use the setParams(int, int) method before
     * starting the animation
     * @param v
     */
    public ResizeAnimation (View v) {
        this.view = v;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {

        view.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (startHeight + deltaHeight * interpolatedTime);
        view.requestLayout();
    }

    /**
     * set the starting and ending height for the resize animation
     * starting height is usually the views current height, the end height is the height
     * we want to reach after the animation is completed
     * @param start height in pixels
     * @param end height in pixels
     */
    public void setParams(int start, int end) {

        this.startHeight = start;
        deltaHeight = end - startHeight;
    }

    /**
     * set the duration for the hideshowanimation
     */
    @Override
    public void setDuration(long durationMillis) {
        super.setDuration(durationMillis);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

In code, **create a new Animation and apply it to the RelativeLayout** that you want to animate:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) ((LinearLayout) view.findViewById(viewId)).getParent();

// getting the layoutparams might differ in your application, it depends on the parent layout
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();

ResizeAnimation a = new ResizeAnimation(relativeLayout);
a.setDuration(500);

// set the starting height (the current height) and the new height that the view should have after the animation
a.setParams(lp.height, newHeight);

relativeLayout.startAnimation(a);
```

Comment: Just used this on a bottom sheet in one of my apps, the only answer that actually worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you! Btw, I added an answer with a slight modification to your code to make it more generic.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for this for hours and Philipp Jahoda's answer was the perfect one since it can be added to an AnimationSet as well. I made a couple of small modifications to support a more similar constructor to the default animation class (except for the View parameter) and to support the "fillEnabled" property.

```
public class ResizeAnimation extends Animation
{

private int startWidth;
private int deltaWidth; // distance between start and end height
private int startHeight;
private int deltaHeight;

private int originalWidth;
private int originalHeight;
private View view;

private boolean fillEnabled = false;


public ResizeAnimation(View v, int startW, int endW, int startH, int endH)
{
    view = v;
    startWidth = startW;
    deltaWidth = endW - startW;

    startHeight = startH;
    deltaHeight = endH - startH;

    originalHeight = v.getHeight();
    originalWidth = v.getWidth();
}

@Override
public void setFillEnabled(boolean enabled)
{
    fillEnabled = enabled;
    super.setFillEnabled(enabled);
}


@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)
{
    if(interpolatedTime == 1.0 && !fillEnabled)
    {
        view.getLayoutParams().height = originalHeight;
        view.getLayoutParams().width = originalWidth;
    }
    else
    {
        if(deltaHeight != 0)
            view.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (startHeight + deltaHeight * interpolatedTime);
        if(deltaWidth != 0)
            view.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (startWidth + deltaWidth * interpolatedTime);
    }

    view.requestLayout();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified, more general (any parameter of layout), Xamarin version.

```
public class SizeAnimation : Animation 
{
    private int _newValue;
    private int _initialValue;
    private string _property;
    private object _target;
    private View _view;

    public SizeAnimation (View view, string property, int newValue)
    {
        _view = view;
        _property = property;
        _newValue = newValue;
        _target = view.LayoutParameters;

        // View measure is generally an enum of wrap_content / fill_parent
        // we need to make the measure explicit
        if (property == "Width" || property == "Height")
        {
            view.Measure ((int)MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified, (int)MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified);
            var unmeasuredValue = (int)view.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(view);
            _initialValue = unmeasuredValue < 1
                ? (int) view.GetType().GetProperty("Measured" + _property).GetValue(view)
                : unmeasuredValue;

            view.LayoutParameters.GetType().GetProperty(property).SetValue(view.LayoutParameters,_initialValue);
        } else
        {
            _initialValue = (int) _target.GetType ().GetProperty (property).GetValue(_target);
        }
    }

    protected override void ApplyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) 
    {
        _target.GetType().GetProperty(_property).SetValue(_target, (int)(_initialValue + (_newValue - _initialValue) * interpolatedTime));
        _view.RequestLayout();  
    }

    public override bool WillChangeBounds() 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var property = "Width";
var value = 120;
var animation = new SizeAnimation(myView, property, value);
animation.Duration = 2000;
animation.Interpolator = (new LinearInterpolator());
myView.StartAnimation(animation);
```

"Theorically" working, not fully tested.

Answer (score 1):

I worked with the answer by `Philipp Jahoda`. Here is an implementation that works for both expand and collapse animations based on the start and end values we pass. Hope it helps.

https://gist.github.com/rahulrvp/dcccd1b78cd09b31a024